# How keep reference to the object navigation property when creating a new object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following as part of the Edit view:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rack.RackID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCEID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rack.timestamp)
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Rack.Technology)
<span class="f"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Rack.Technology.Tag, new 
{ @readonly = "readonly" })</span>
 <span class="f">Rack Name </span> 


@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCENAME)

             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCENAME)                                              
</div>

<div >
<span class="f">Product Name </span> 

    @Html.DropDownList("productName", ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.ComponentDefinition>)ViewBag.Products).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.COMPONENTNAME), 
        Value = option.COMPONENTNAME.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Resource.ComponentDefinition !=   null ) && (option.COMPONENTNAME == Model.Resource.ComponentDefinition.COMPONENTNAME)
    }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resource.COMPONENTID)
</div>


   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    }</div>
```

I have the following Post Edit action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(RackJoin rj,FormCollection formValues)
        {
            string controllername = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var message = "";
                    var status = "";
                    long assetid = new long();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
                        foreach (string key in formValues)
                        {
                            query[key] = this.Request.Form[key];
                        }
```

and the RackJoin model class is :-

```
public class RackJoin
    {
        public Rack Rack { get; set; }
        public Resource Resource { get; set; }}
```

but the problem I am facing is that when I post back the object to the Post Edit action method, I will loose all its navigation properties such as (Rack.Technology, Rack.SiteDefinistion) , so how I can maintain all the object navigation properties, so if the Post edit action methods wants to access these navigation properties or the edit view is rendered after a model state error they will not get a null reference exception .

Comment: As long as you are persisting the model information in the view (which you appear to be doing) and posting it to the server then the information should be retained.

Comment: this what i am trying to do , but it failed. for example i though that writting "@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Rack.Technology)" will post back the Technology navigation proprty for the Rack, but writting this hidden field will make the model.state to be false as the mvc will not be able to convert the Rack.Technology into a string !

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML being generated? It should look similar to `<input type="hidden" name="RackJoin.Rack.Technology" value="..." />`. I would go back to basics, start with a very simple model (with less properties) and incrementally introduce the properties until you hit one which causes the problem.

Comment: i already check , and writing the following "@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Rack.Technology)", will raise the following model state error:- "Exception {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'TMS.Models.Technology' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
"

Comment: Clearly that's what the issue is then, if `Technology` is a complex type than it can't be rendered as a hidden field as a whole. You need to persist the *individual* properties of `Technology` instead e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rack.Technology.Name)`.

Comment: i got your point. so i will end up writing about 6 hidden fields inside my edit view ? is this normal to have ? is it normal inside mvc views, to manually write hidden fields inside edit view?

Comment: yes it's normal, you can use [editor templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx) to simplify it and call it as `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rack.Technology)`. However, see my answer I think the real issue is with your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is because `Technology` is a complex type so can't be rendered via `HiddenFor`, if you need to persist all the information for this property you will have to individually render each property e.g.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rack.Technology.Name)
```

However, I am beginning to question your design here. If a lot of the information is irrelevant to this particular view then in fact it shouldn't even be there. View models should be tailored to the view so I would recommend you have a *specific* model designed to capture the relevant information only i.e.

```
public class RackJoinViewModel
{
    public int RackID { get; set; }
    public int ResourceID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Technology { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This should simplify the view rendering as there are no complex types e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RackID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResourceID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TimeStamp)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Technology)
    ...
}
```

Not only is this cleaner but it also eradicates the problem of trying to persist irrelevant information across the request.